# Найти сколько прошло времени с момента нажатия на кнопку

Tags: swift

сейчас пишу программу на языке swift и столкнулся с такой проблемой, мне надо найти сколько минут прошло с момента нажатия на кнопку, я реализовал это так:

```
import UIKit
let date = Date()

let calendar = Calendar.current

class CollectingViewController: UIViewController {

    var minute1 : Int = 0
    var minute2 : Int = 0
    @IBAction func StartButton(_ sender: Any) {
        minute1 = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var WorkedMoney: UILabel!

    @IBAction func ShowMoneyButton(_ sender: Any) {
        minute2 = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        WorkedMoney.text = String(minute2 - minute1)
    }
```

Я жду долго после нажатия на первую кнопку, но всегда выводиться результат 0, обьясните почему? я не понимаю почему вторая переменная не равна тому времени при котором я нажимаю на вторую кнопку (minute1 почему то всегда равна minute2) обьясните пожалуйста что не так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это из-за того, что вы неправильно получаете текущую дату. Вы один раз получаете ее вне класса (в строке *let date = Date()*) и потом извлекаете минуты **из одной и той же даты**, которая хранится у вас в переменной date, и которую вы получаете не при нажатии на кнопки, а при старте программы.

Вам надо эту строку вообще убрать, а дату извлекать в каждой из строчек получения количества минут, то есть эти строчки у вас должны выглядеть вот так:

> minute1 = calendar.component(.minute, from: Date())

и

> minute2 = calendar.component(.minute, from: Date())

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать используя Timer из стандартной библиотеки Foundation.

Сначала делаем объявление таймера, переменной в которой будет лежать время запуска таймера startTime, и переменной timeInSec в которой будет лежать пройденное время в секундах:

```
var timer: Timer?
var startTime: Double!
var timeInSec: Int!
```

В момент нажатия на кнопку мы вызываем функцию start которая запустит таймер:

```
func startTimer() {
    startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1,
                                 target: self,
                                 selector: #selector(updateTimer(timer:)),
                                 userInfo: nil,
                                 repeats: true)
}
```

И с помощью функции updateTimer мы будем записывать в переменную timeInSec свежее значение таймера:

```
func updateTimer(timer: Timer) {
    timeInSec = Int(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime)        
}
```

Теперь в переменной timeInSec будет лежать время прошедшее со старта таймера.

Comment: Для функции updateTimer нужно проставить атрибут @objc